# Call Stored Procedure in SSIS via OLEDB Source with multi value parameter

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to call a stored procedure that has 3 input parameters. The stored proc has multiple joins, populates multiple temp tables etc. I need to call this SP from one database and populate another database table in SQL server. I am trying to use OLEDB Source SQL Command

I have also created 3 variables in SSIS package(same variables are in stored proc parameters)

```
     @date string
     @productType string
     @Flag int32

      Exec getDetails
       ?,?,?

also mapped parameters tab
Parameter-Date variables:user::Date
ProductType-variables:user::ProductType
Flag -variables:user::Flag
```

First parameter is a date field-get specific `date` data
second parameter-product type that has 20 different possible values(we want to pull all product types for one date )
third -just a value either 1 or 0.
 I also need to map columns from SP to destination table. some columns are unnecessary from sproc and mapping should be done. I am getting **error** as

> Exception-HRESULT:0Xc020204A An OLEDB record is availab.e-Source
>   Microsoft SQL Sever Native Client 11.0 HResult-0*80004005
>
> Error at data flow task(OLEDB Source)-Unable to retrieve column
>   information from the data source. Make sure your target table in
>   database is available. Need help loading data from this stored proc to
>   a destination table.

Comment: Have you tried to hard code the parameters to see if its an issue with the variables themselves?

Comment: In ssms i am able to execute sproc as exec getDetails’20180705’,’apple;orange;mango;pear;cherry’, 1 dont want to add all 20 values here. How do i assign all the possible 20  values to a parameters in ssis? Should u seperate with commas or semi colon?  Single quote is not required if i recall

Comment: What about when you hardcore them in ssis?

Comment: Will try with hard coding all possible values and run

Comment: I googled your error and this was the first response: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/3808e4b8-d11a-4c65-915e-3f4a6087b5ab/error-unable-to-retrieve-column-information-from-the-data-source?forum=sqlintegrationservices. It's possible your SP doesn't return columns, or has inconsistent columns returned. If your SP has a few different `SELECT` statements in it, or if it selects from a temp table. this might be the issue. Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

`Declare
@date string,
@productType string,
@Flag int32`

`set @date = ?
set @productType = ?
set @Flag = ?`

`Exec getDetails @date, productType, @flag`

Please make sure map the variable as in same sequece

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your response. 
Step1
I actually used a different method creating another stored proc and called the other sp(called sp cant be modified). Created a temp table, inserted result of called sp into a temp table and populated the result sets of temp into target table. 
- passed possible values to productType, flag was passed value as 1, and date was selected as max
Step 2-created SSIS package, used execute sql task to call sproc

It worked